# Extracting csv file names without extension R

Tags: r

I have a folder with different files. What I'm trying to do is to extract file names without extensions of csv files only.

for example:
if i have a folder with files

```
cp1.csv 
cp2.csv 
sd.exe
```

I'd like to get a vector:

```
"cp1" "cp2"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a `list.files()` `gsub()` combo

```
basenames<-gsub("\\.csv$","", list.files(pattern="\\.csv$"))
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to `gsub` would be `file_path_sans_extension` from "tools". Try:

```
library(tools)
file_path_sans_ext(list.files(pattern = "*.csv"))
```

Not much added here, but it's still a fun function to know about :-)